# How to find the interrupt numbers form a design?

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux

Given a VIVADO design on ZYNQ 7000 board and asked to run an Linux application through UIO, one needs to find weather the Kernel is properly configured or not. One can use petalinux to generate the required files. Proper interrupts neeeds to generated on the `/proc/interrupts` . The question is given the design and the .xsa file, how and what steps are required to fine the necessary interrups in the `/proc/interrupts`?

Comment: This search hit looks interesting [how-to-use-interrupts-on-zynqsoc](https://prof.bht-berlin.de/fileadmin/prof/svoss/CES/Datenblaetter/how-to-use-interrupts-on-zynqsoc.pdf)

Comment: @Mikef Thank you so much for the link. It is definitely interesting. I will read it, I wished they had an example related to AXI DMA.

Comment: /proc/interrupts is about Linux IRQ nmbering which may be not 1:1 to the hardware. Depending on the output in that file it may or may not be possible.